# Plot Data from CSV and group values in colum

Tags: python, pandas, csv, dataframe

I am pretty new in python and try to understand how to do the following:

I am trying to plot data from a csv file where I have values for A values for B and values for C. How can I group it and plot it based on the Valuegroup and as values using the colum values?

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

csv_loader = pd.read_csv('C:/Test.csv', encoding='cp1252', sep=';', index_col=0).dropna()
#csv_loader.plot()

print(csv_loader)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()
csv_loader.groupby('Valuegroup').plot(x='Date', y='Value', ax=ax, legend=False, kind='line')
```

The data looks like the following:

```
Calcgroup;Valuegroup;id;Date;Value
Group1;A;1;20080103;0.1
Group1;A;1;20080104;0.3
Group1;A;1;20080107;0.5
Group1;A;1;20080108;0.9
Group1;B;1;20080103;0.5
Group1;B;1;20080104;1.3
Group1;B;1;20080107;2.0
Group1;B;1;20080108;0.15
Group1;C;1;20080103;1.9
Group1;C;1;20080104;2.1
Group1;C;1;20080107;2.9
Group1;C;1;20080108;0.45
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to take a mean of `Value` for each `Valuegroup` and show them with line chart, use

```
csv_loader.groupby('Valuegroup')['Value'].mean().plot()
```

There are various chart types available, please refer to [pandas documentation on plot](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.plot.html)

Comment: thanks a lot for your help. I receive the following error message: KeyError: 'Valuegroup'

Comment: I edited my solution. Please try again. The name of your dataframe is `csv_loader`, while my initial solution used `df`